# drop down menu issue

Tags: html, css

I am having a drop down menu issue. I wanted to put my menu on the top- right side but every time I resize the screen size, the menu starts falling on the bottom. 
how to make it fixed on the multiple screen sizes?

thanks

[http://jsfiddle.net/6YZ8w/]

Comment: please make [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: you can working with media queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: try giving `nav ul li { position:relative; }` and for better solution add your html code.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/aeFx3/1/)

```
Do you want like this?

It is not clear from your question how the design should be.

BTW, the links were coming out because you were giving the inside div's position:absolute. So the links were losing relation with the main div Nav.
```

If you want to know more about working of positioning in CSS then go through this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position).

Comment: yes that one looks fine, plz check the link that I left on my post. I am not sure why when I resize the small screen it keeps fallings.

Answer (score 0):

you can try implemting the below example

```
.mymenu {
    widht:100%;
    background: url(../images/mbg.png) #F00;
    height:40px;
    border-bottom: #21b8ff solid 4px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.mymenu .menu {
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.mymenu .menu a{
    margin-top:3px;
    float:right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: SC_DUBAI;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-right: #4c4c4c solid 1px;
    border-left: #818181 solid 1px;
    height:40px;
}

.mymenu .menu a:hover{
    color:#636363;
    background: #21b8ff;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7tmK/) is working fine.